# Bind issues with Bluebird promises

Tags: javascript, promise, bluebird

I am having some difficulties with promises and bind.

I have 2 clases:

```
// A Model/DB connnection of sorts
function Connection() {

}
Connection.prototype.findOrder = function(id) {
  // Returns promise
}


// The main class 
function Main(connector) {
  this.connector = connector;
}

Main.prototype.buildInvoice = function(report) {
  return P.map(ids, self.connector.findOrder.bind(self, id);
  // Yields: Cannot read property 'bind' of undefined
};
```

Called like this:

```
var connection = new Connection({
  connection: config.db.mongo.connection
});

var main = new Main({ connection: connection });

P.each(reports, main.buildInvoice.bind(main));
```

I am running into bind issues. I was first getting this error for the line above:

```
Unhandled rejection TypeError: undefined is not a function
```

I subsequently added the `bind` found on `P.each(reports, main.buildInvoice.bind(main));`. However the same issue came up for the buildInvoice method but I have not managed to figure out the syntax. The code as posted yields `Cannot read property 'bind' of undefined`

What is the correct syntax to make this call:

```
Main.prototype.buildInvoice = function(report) {
  var self = this;
  return P.map(ids, self.connector.findOrder.bind(self, id);
};
```

This is probably a non promise related issue but i am posting as this as I am at the same time wondering if I am handling this flow correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For one thing, your call `new Main({ connection: connection });` doesn't match your constructor function:

```
function Main(connector) {
  this.connector = connector;
}
```

which expects the connection to be passed by itself, not wrapped in an object. Therefore, when setting `.connector` to that object you pass in, its `.findOrder` will be `undefined`. Use

```
var main = new Main(connection);
```

Second, you will need to [bind](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) the `findOrder` method to the connection object, not to `self`. Oh, and `self` is called `this` in JS. And there's no `id` that you want to partially apply. So use

```
Main.prototype.buildInvoice = function(report) {
  return P.map(ids, this.connector.findOrder.bind(this.connector));
};
```

Comment: omg the silly mistakes.... more coffee!! The 'self' was a missing line which I have edited. Yes the silly connection call was the issue.